# pmudt_50005: [ERROR] Failed to process data:Can't find RepeatingGroup

Tags: json, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I'm getting the below error while using Unstructured Data Transformation

```
pmudt_50005: [ERROR] Failed to process data:Can't find RepeatingGroup.
```

I have parsed json file in Data Transformation Studio and integrated with PowerCenter. But it's failing with above error. What can I try to resolve this?

It's getting parsed while executing in Data Transformation Studio.

Comment: Hi - I think you'll need to provide a lot more information that that in order for anyone to be able to help you e.g. what version of Informatica are you using; provide a sample of the JSON file; provide the output you are trying to create from that JSON file; provide the logic you are using to convert the JSON to that output; etc...

Comment: The issue is integration of DT studio with informatica powercenter

Comment: I know you already did this but 1. i would like to check the json first to see if its in correct format and validate using jsonformatter. 2. seems like its informatica transformation that can not read /process the definition. so can you pls modify and keep minimum structure to see if there is some other issue. Also check visually if there is some discrepancy. 3. if possible post the json here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because the file is getting parsed line by line in informatica power center. Instead it has to parse all the data set as a single line. For this we have to specify the inconsistent delimiter which will never occur in the data or import the file as fixed width.